# TypeError: Cannot create property 'href' on string 'about:blank'

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, electron

Ran into an error after testing the Firebase authentication with Google on ElectronJS.

Authentication used to work before, even though I haven't made any significant changes in my code that would affect the Google authentication part.

Authentication still works correctly when I am running my project in the browser (npm run serve). In Electron I can see the

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'href' on string 'about:blank' when clicking on the Google authentication button.
```

[TypeError: Cannot create property 'href' on string 'about:blank'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bus3t.png)

My code that is being executed on click -

```
googleLogin() {
  fb.auth
    .signInWithPopup(fb.googleProvider)
    .then(credential => {
      this.$store.commit("setCurrentUser", credential.user)

      fb.usersCollection.doc(credential.user.uid).set({

      }).then(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserProfile")
        this.updateGmailData()
        this.$router.push("/dashboard")
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

On second click on the button, I can see another typeError -

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'href' on string ''
```

Why does the authentication work on browser but not in Electron?
What is the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

see this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1334.

Electron is not officially supported by Firebase Auth. Since Electron is a combination of a browser and Node.js server environment, some features may not work as expected, such as signInWithPopup.

But [@diggabyte](https://github.com/diggabyte) (thx to him) seems to have found a way to handle it:

> I was able to get it to work via signInWithRedirect + getRedirectResult
>   https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1334#issuecomment-434094783